# TCP: Address already in use exception - possible causes for client port? NO PORT EXHAUSTION

Tags: windows, tcp, port

stupid problem. I get those from a client connecting to a server. Sadly, the setup is complicated making debugging complex - and we run out of options.

The environment:
*Client/Server system, both running on the same machine. The client is actually a service doing some database manipulation at specific times.
* The cnonection comes from C# going through OleDb to an EasySoft JDBC driver to a custom written JDBC server that  then hosts logic in C++. Yeah, compelx - but the third party supplier decided to expose the extension mechanisms for their server through a JDBC interface. Not a lot can be done here ;)

The Symptom:
At (ir)regular intervals we get a "Address already in use: connect" told from the JDBC driver. They seem to come from one particular service we run.

Now, I did read all the stuff about port exhaustion. This is why we have a little tool running now that counts ports and their states every minute. Last time this happened, we had an astonishing 370 ports in use, with the count rising to about 900 AFTER the error. We aleady patched the registry (it is a windows machine) to allow more than the 5000 client ports standard, but even then, we are far far from that limit to start with.

Which is why I am asking here. Ayneone an ide what ELSE could cause this?

It is a Windows 2003 Server machine, 64 bit. The only other thing I can see that may cause it (but this functionality is supposedly disabled) is Symantec Endpoint Protection that is installed on the server - and being capable of actinc as a firewall, it could possibly intercept network traffic. I dont want to open a can of worms by pointing to Symantec prematurely (if pointing to Symantec can ever be seen as such). So, anyone an idea what else may be the cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Address already in use", aka WSAEADDRINUSE (10048), means that when the client socket prepared to connect to the server socket, it first tried to bind itself to a specific local IP/Port pair that was already in use by another socket, either an active one or one that has been closed but is still in the FD_WAIT state.  This has nothing to do with the number of ports that are available.

Comment: ... and that is something that clients should rarely if ever do. There is no advantage and several disadvantages including this one.

Comment: This is not right. The client works fine and uses a random port - this can be seen (unless we get a stupid once in a week error here). Load tests in our test environment work fine with 20 times the load.

The error is ALSO related to port exhaustion. Check for example https://www.socketlabs.com/support/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=23

or

http://forums.parasoft.com/index.php?showtopic=435

And this is what we dont run into per our own logging program dumping all socket states every minute.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same issue on a Windows 2000 Server with a .Net application connecting to a SQL Server 7.0. There's like 10 servers with the same configuration and only one is showing this error several times a day. With a small test program I'm able to reproduce the error by just establishing a TCP connection on the SQL Server listening port. Running CurrPorts (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) shows there's still plenty of available ports in range 1024-5000.

I'm out of ideas and would like to know if you've found a solution since you've posted your question.

Edit : I finally found the solution : a worm was present on the server (WORM_DOWNAD.A) and exhausted local ports without being noticed.