# Listening on same port, different IP address, WCF + non-WCF app

Tags: .net, wcf, networking, tcp

I have an application binding on port IP1:80 of a machine with 5 virtual IP addresses (IP1-IP5)

I then try to bind a self-hosted WCF service to IP5:80 but get an AlreadyInUseException. I guess WCF is trying to bind to the entire IP range, despite the fact that I specify a specific one.

Is this known behaviour?

```
            [start application that binds to IP1:80]


            string baseAddress = "http://IP5:80/binary";

            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(BinaryService),
                                               new Uri(baseAddress));


            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IBinaryService), GetBinding(), "")
                                   .Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

            host.Open(); // exception
```

Comment: What makes you "guess WCF is trying to bind the entire IP range"? Can't the port on that IP just be in use, similar to [this situation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2399920/419956)?

Comment: The reason I think this: I can run another instance of the non-wcf app on IP5:80 and it works just fine. WCF on the other hand will only start if the port is free on all IPs.

Comment: Is "IP5" the *name* of the computer?  WCF will bind to the computer, not a specific IP address if you do it that way...

Comment: no it's an ip address. see solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
Run netsh
Type http
Type add iplisten ipaddress=IP5:80
```

After this, self-hosted WCF app will not try and bind to the full range on 80, just IP5!